# What is the connection between NSDocumentController and the app delegate?

Tags: cocoa, appdelegate, document-based, nsdocumentcontroller

I'm trying to understand the structure of a Cocoa document based application. I understand that the *app delegate* responds to events from the application (hence its name) and that the *document controller* manages all documents and open and save etc. What I'm not understanding is the connection between the *document controller* and the *app delegate*, and perhaps the rest of the application.

I'm studying this image, found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW6).

[image]

The arrow seems to indicate some kind of connection between the *app delegate* and the *document controller*.

**What connection do they have?**

Edit: I realize that this is a very academic question, that might no be so necessary, but I want to understand why these things are as they are.